# ImageView appears in the wrong place in LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-linearlayout

I'm following a tutorial from Head First Android Development and I can't figure out why LinearLayout is not working as it should.

Here is the xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test_image_title"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test_image_date"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/test_image"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test_image_description"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the image goes in the middle, but the image should be just under the two lines of text displayed on the upper side, not in the middle.  Also the last TextView isn't shown at all. Everything should show in order as declared in xml.

Aleast that's what the tutorial showed.

I tried putting ImageView part on top of TextViews and then i get no text at all and image is still in the middle.

Now has the behavior changes since the book was released or am I missing something?

Comment: Is this something you see on Design View or in the actual app?

Comment: What is the height of test_image in pixels?

Comment: See if you get correct behaviour after commenting out the ImageView. If you see the text appear in correct order then something is wrong with your ImageView. Can you post size and type of the "@drawable/test_image" ?

Comment: Try setting the `ImageView` size to something small like 56dp*56dp or put a `<ScrollView>` around the `<LinearLayout>`. Something tells me the image is too big.

Comment: The image size is 1000x773.

Comment: I changed the size to 400dp x 300dp and then it works as intended.

So it seems that the width gets scaled to screen, but height still remains and blocks out the space 773 pixels. However the image looks great and fits to screen.

I thought that wrap_content sets the height to something normal.

Can I use something instead of wrap_content then to have a normal height?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer from: [ImageView in android XML layout with layout_height="wrap_content" has padding top & bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553913/imageview-in-android-xml-layout-with-layout-height-wrap-content-has-padding-to)

You need to add this to ImageView:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

For some reason wrap_content does not work for height without that line.

Answer (score 0):

You may to use `wrap_content` if you don't know how long the text or you can't specify the image height and weight, but you must define the `ImageView` and `TextView` position on `LinearLayout`. For example, you can define the `ImageView` position using: `android:paddingLeft`, `android:paddingTop`, `android:layout_centerHorizontal`, `android:layout_alignParentTop`, etc. This is how I use that code on `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image_resource" />
```

And how I use the `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:text="My TextView1"/>
```

You can find another `android:[position]` attributes and how to use it on Google.

Answer (score -1):

As your question above, if your layout defined correctly like in your sample, it will display 4 lines and the your component displayed each lines. Try to change android:orientation="**vertical**" to **horizontal** to display full component fill each lines, sorry if I misunderstanding

Comment: No, he wants the views aligned vertically. It looks correct to me.